# How to fixed Position of dyanamic dropdown list when select the option

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working with `Wordpress` and I am using the dynamically `drop-down` list

when I select the `option` then drop-down list automatically change its position

means It does not fixed,I want to fixed  a particular place  for drop down

list.
here is [the link](http://demoaiindustries.com/yummmy/product)

Answer (score 2):

Change this css

```
.wppp-select {
    bottom:inherit;
    position: absolute;
    top: -60px !important;
}
```

this css line no.344

```
demoaiindustries.com/yummmy/wp-content/themes/yummy_child/style.css
```